# ¿Como validar un switch e insertarlo en la base de datos si el dato en mi db es booleano?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, materialize

Tengo un formulario al cual ingreso los datos del personal, pero para darle un aspecto mas elegante a la vista del usuario le he insertado un componente switch para 'validar' si ese 'personaje' estará activo o inactivo, que se guardara como true o false en mi base de datos mysql.

El problema seria ¿como manipular este componente para que cuando envié los datos a mi BD valide si es true o false y lo guarde?

El único código que tengo es este, ya que porque es donde debería empezar pero no sabría como, obviamente es la primera ves que lo uso...

```
  <div class="switch">
    <label>
      Off
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="lever"></span>
      On
    </label>
  </div>
```

Agradecería su colaboración.

Comment: Utilizas alguna librería para el "switch"?

Comment: A qué te refieres con que la BD **VALIDE** si es true o false? Solo crea un a columna en la tabla que sea boolean (TINYINT) y lo guardas ahí sin problemas

Comment: @JuankGlezz uso materialize.css

Comment: @user2930137...ok y cuando guarde el como sabe que le ha enviado un tru o un false? la modificacion deberia de hacerse en el 'componente' no?

Comment: Usa un 0 o 1 es un integer , te dejas de complicaciones. int(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el backend reciba algo, tu checkbox tiene que estar en estado `checked` y **tiene que tener un nombre**. Si no le pones atributo `value`, por defecto enviará el valor `on` cuando esté checkeado. Pero para simplificar las cosas, pongámosle valor 1.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="micampo" value="1">
```

Cuando está checkeado, el backend recibe 1. Cuando no está checkeado, el backend no recibe nada, como si el checkbox no existiera.

Por eso, la técnica más comun es anteponer un input de tipo `hidden` con el mismo nombre, cosa que si el checkbox está desactivado, ese input se encargue de mandar un cero, false u off al backend.

```
<input type="hidden" name="micampo" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="micampo" value="1"/>
```

Esto se puede probar en el ejemplo de más abajo. Toma en cuenta que en esa serialización, el último que declara el valor de un name es el que vale, por lo que

```
backend.php?micampo=0&micampo=1
```

Equivale a

```
backend.php?micampo=1
```

```js
jQuery('#comprobar').on('click',function() {
  console.log('Voy a enviar',jQuery('#miformulario').serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miformulario">
<input type="hidden" name="micampo" value="0"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="micampo" value="1"/>
<input type="button" id="comprobar" value="comprobar"/>
</form>
```

Respecto al "componente" en realidad el switch no es más que un efecto cosmético que agrega materialize. Tu checkbox sigue tal cual, pero invisible.

PD: esto evidentemente se puede hacer sin jQuery, pero materialize de por sí tiene a jQuery como dependencia.

Answer (score 1):

Para un caso ingresas en la tabla un valor `0` o `1` dependiendo de si está activo o no.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["check"])){
        echo "esta ok";
    }else{
        echo "no esta ok";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```